# PowerShell Project

Tags: powershell, scripting, remote-desktop

I've got a project to do for my job, and it goes like this:
I have to connect to around 60 remote desktop connections (all with the same credentials) not at once, but one at a time (which I managed to) with:

```
PowerShell.exe mstsc /v:IP (with credentials saved for the connection, this means that I have to make around 60 scripts, but no problem with that)
```

but now I get a disclaimer about security and so on, and I would need to press 'ENTER'(for which I didn't find a solution). Next up I would've to open an instance of Chrome(on remote) and go to a specific address(e.g.192.168.1.0) on whom I would need to copy all the information from the address(from the Chrome window on remote)(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) into a .txt back to local machine.

*I mention that I don't know programming of any kind of language, all I know is to put some commands one after another.
If anyone would be kind enough to help me I would appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: If these machines are in the same domain as your PowerShell server, you're much better off enabling PowerShell remoting (if it's not already enabled) and using `Invoke-Command` to do your work (and downloading on the machine can be done with `Invoke-WebRequest` rather than Chrome).

Comment: This sounds like it might be an XY problem. What is the purpose of this? What information are you trying to save to the local file? What is the end goal?

Comment: I don't really know if my laptop and the machines are on the same powershell server. The end purpose of this project would be to collect information once per week from equipments(available on a link) connected to the remote PCs. After that. the data would be uploaded on a site/tool.
Thank you!

Comment: What sort of data?

Comment: Mainly IDs, IPs and Names(raw data), found on link(e.g. LNCEL26548) wich need to be extracted later.

Comment: This is a non-trivial coding problem. You need to do some research and try writing some code. Depending on what the data is and where it comes from, you may be able to access the data directly. The last resort should be trying to run an app on the client and try to SendKeys or screen scrape.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for the answers, I will get back with the result.